# Can I use 跳舞 into these three words?

Tags: word

跳那舞
跳华尔兹
跳奇怪舞

All of these three words can be used?
I think the second word is possible
Thank you in advance

Comment: 跳那个舞，跳那支舞 sounds better to me. And I don't quite get "跳奇怪舞", maybe you want to say "跳奇怪的舞"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

跳舞 is 离合词, so you could separate. Example: 跳个舞，舞你会跳吧， 跳拉丁舞。

Here is some corrections for your examples: 跳那种舞 instead of 跳那舞；跳华尔兹 is good; 跳奇怪的舞 sounds better than 跳奇怪舞;

Comment: Can I also say 跳舞蹈?

Comment: @HarutoNagasaki, 跳舞蹈 is good too.

Comment: Can you teach me https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/27541/18198?

Comment: By the way, why 那 can't be?

Comment: 跳那舞 is not natural as 跳那种舞. 那 is seldom used alone, it's often used in a set, like 那种，那类， 那个， 哪些，...