# In a set word, can't I use a complement between it?

Tags: word-choice, word

For example, in 明心 that each can't stand alone, can it be used into 明完心 or 明了心? If not, why?

Comment: You can, if you’re using it as a V.O. that means: “express one's idea”

Comment: Sorry but can you teach me https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/27539/18198

Comment: What do you mean by 明心?

Comment: 《现代汉语词典》 has notes in word explanation that show whether it can be used in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

明心 can mean:

> 1. 心思清明纯正: purity in mind;
> 2. 表明心迹: express one's thought;

明心 is not that common. It's often heard in 明心静气.

I haven't heard 明完心 so far. But 明了...心 is possible because 明了 [míng liǎo] is a set word meaning 'be clear about'. For example, 明了你的心 meaning I understand what you think.

Comment: What about 明我的心 明心明的大

Comment: 明我的心 is ok. 明心明的大 is awkward.

Comment: Someone said it wrong without 白

Comment: What's your opinion of it?

Comment: 明我的心 and 明白我的心 have different meaning. 明我的心 is short for 表明我的心， meaning express my heart/thought. 明白我的心 means 'to understand my heart/thought'.

Answer (score 1):

明完心，明了心，there are not expressions like this in Chinese

Comment: I mean using a compliment 完 了

Comment: Not as a complete word

Comment: I have never seen that，maybe you mean 明白了or明白？

Comment: But someone said it can be used

Comment: Sorry, as a Chinese, I didn't get your idea

Comment: I mean 吃饭 I eat rice 吃完饭 I've already eaten rice

Comment: 吃完饭 is OK，but 明完心or 明了心 is an incorrect expression

Comment: Oh so 明我的心 is also wrong?

Comment: And 明心明得大 is also wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can say 明白我的心

Comment: I mean without 白

Comment: It's wrong without白

Comment: Sorry but can you teach me  明心明得大 is also wrong?

Comment: Yes,it's wrong. Even I can't get your meaning of those words

Comment: That means show one's mind and that action is big

Comment: Can I say 跳舞 into 跳那舞 meaning do that dance?

Comment: 深深地明白？You can say this

Comment: Yes, but 跳那支舞 is better

Comment: What about 跳完舞?

Comment: Please help me ;_;

Comment: What about 跳舞跳得很快

Comment: 跳完舞and跳舞跳得很快 are good

Comment: By the way someone above said 明我的心 is possible

Comment: In some Chinese ancient and modern poems, 明我的心is right, but it's absolutely not common in spoken and written Chinese nowadays

Comment: What about 明心明得很慢

Comment: It's also ancient phrase?

Comment: 明心明得很慢is really awkward. You can say明白得很慢or理解得很慢，besides,明心is not common even it's an awkward expression in my view